# Can't able to create mock in inheritance relationship with spock

Tags: spock

I am new to spock.I have created mock object in normal class its works fine. But when we have inheritance like structure as below then I can't able to mock the things properly its gives error (null pointer). Any one have idea how we can do it in spock.

```
Class Parent{
    Third getThird(){
        return third;
    }
}

Class Child extend Parent{
    Object method1(){
        String msg=getThird().someMethod(); // need to mock this line
        return object;
    }   
}

given:
    Third third=Mock()
    Child child=new Child()
    child.getThird(false) >> third
    third.someMethod() >>  "xyz"
when :
Object object=child.method1()
then:
//comparing the things
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?:

```
given:
    def third = Mock(Third)
    Child.metaClass.getThird = {
        third
    } 
when :
    Object object=child.method1()
then:
    1 * thirdMocked.someMethod() >> "xyz"
and:
    //comparing the things
cleanup:
    Child.metaClass = null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mock classes in Spock like any interfaces :

```
given:
    def thirdMock = Mock(Third) {
      someMethod() >> "xyz"
    }
    def child = Mock(Child) {
      third >> thirdMock
    }
when :
  def object = child.method1()
then:
  //comparing the things
```

however, it's usualy a symptom of a code not really testable. in your case, you should probably make 'third' injectable, and then inject a mock.